# Why does the limit of $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{z^4}}}{z}$ not exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

My teacher said without explaining that the limit of $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{z^4}}}{z}$, $z\rightarrow 0$, where $z$ is a complex number doesn't exist. Why is this true?

Comment: Because it has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: Because the limit is different depending on how you approach $0$.

Comment: @Arthur, but why does the way you approach $z=0$ change the limit?

Comment: Try approaching along the positive real axis, and then try approaching from the direction of $1+i$. You will get very different results.

Comment: Not that I have a problem with you asking here, but did you ask your teacher, by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequences
$$
a_n=\dfrac1n,\quad b_n=\dfrac1ne^{i\pi/4}.
$$
They both converge to $0$, i.e. 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0,
$$
but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{a_n^4}}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{-n^4}=0,
$$
while
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{b_n^4}}}{b_n}=e^{-i\pi/4}\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{n^4}=\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to prove this is using power series.

$$e^z = \sum_0^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

So

$$e^\frac{-1}{z^4} = \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{4n}n!}$$

And

$$\frac{e^\frac{-1}{z^4}}{z} = \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{4n+1}n!}$$

This certainly has no finite limit. It has an essential singularity at $0$ so by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem it has no limit (not even $\infty$) at $0$.